# how to get value of var in file with sed

Tags: sed

i would like to to that :
The file containe :

```
VAR_1|VALU_1
VAR_2|VALU_2
VAR_3|VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33
VAR_4|VALU_4
VAR_5|VALU_5
VAR_6|VALU_61
VALU_62
VAR_7|VALU_7
.....
```

How can i get the value of a string with sed or other?

I try :

```
sed -n '/^VAR_3|*/,/^[A-Z_]+/{;p}'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Imagining your input is saved in a file called "test.txt", you can use "awk" with the following syntax:

`awk -F '|' '/^VAR_3/ {print $2}' test.txt`

Sample execution for the input you gave:

```
$ awk -F '|' '/^VAR_3/ {print $2}' test.txt
VALU_31
```

Here's a basic explanation of this awk command:

`-F '|'` : defines "|" (pipe symbol) as the field separator
`/^VAR_3/` : only matches lines that start with "VAR_3"
`{print $2}` : prints the second field / column (that, in this case, contains the value that you want to print)

**UPDATE (Dec 3, 2015):**

So, the OP has added a clarifying comment, which leads to conclude that he wants the search to be multiline, considering the lines between two "tokens" as part of the value of the first token.

Here's a revised version for the initial example, this time using the "**sed**" (2 times!) and "**head**" commands:

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_3|//' | head -n -1
VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33
```

OK. That looks good **:-)** Let's see if that holds for a single line case:

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_4|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_4|//' | head -n -1
VALU_4
```

Good. So it also works for single line cases!

Does it work well if the string searched is NOT in the input? Let's try it for `VAR_0` (that does NOT exist in the given example):

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_0|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_0|//' | head -n -1  
$
```

Great. So this seems to be working in several cases (although I guess there may be more efficient solutions).

So, how does this work? Here's the basic rundown for the "VAR_3" example...

The first part - `sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt` - returns the following output:

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt
VAR_3|VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33
VAR_4|VALU_4
```

So, that part basically matches everything between `VAR_3` and the next ocurrence of `VAR_`. As we see, this part seems to be returning what we want... PLUS two things that we do NOT want: the "`VAR_3|`" in the first line -AND- the last line.

So, we pipe this first output to another "sed" instruction that only applies to the first line, and we replace the string "`VAR_3|`" by nothing, effectively removing it:

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_3|//'
VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33
VAR_4|VALU_4
```

The "`1`" is for applying the sed command to the first line... And we want to NOT include that last line, so we pipe that output to the "**head**" command with the "`-n`" ("MINUS n") switch - specifically "`-n 1`" to exclude the last line:

```
$ sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/VAR_/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_3|//' | head -n -1
VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33
```

Comment: Yes it's print "VALU_31" but not "VALU_31
VALU_31
VALU_33"

Comment: @kgoul: OK... it wasn't clear (at least for me), in your initial question, that was your goal. I'll edit my answer to cover that case.

Comment: @kgoul: OK. I added an updated version that I believe does what you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

That great. I would like to replace "VAR_" in
"sed -n  '/VAR_3|/,/**VAR_**/p' test.txt | sed '1 s/VAR_3|//' | head -n -1"
by sothing like that :
sed -n  "/$SEEK|/,/**^[A-Z_-]+\|**/p" get-server-infos.txt | sed "1 s/$SEEK|//" | head -n -1

My VARS name ares always formated like that "^[A-Z_-]+|*"
Start with letter uppercase and can contain "-" and "_" and always contain "|".

Thx a lot for your help.